# Can a bipedal eidolon ride a mount?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, mount, summoner, eidolon

If I level up my eidolon's ride skill, can I have it ride into battle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a bipedal eidolon, and not a "humanoid" eidolon:

According to the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ride/) any points in ride describe a creature that is "skilled at riding mounts, usually a horse, but possibly something more exotic, like a griffon or pegasus. If you attempt to ride a creature that is ill suited as a mount, you take a –5 penalty on your Ride checks."

It stands to reason that any creature with a ride skill would be able to ride a mount.
The logistics of a limbless being, (for example, an aquatic eidolon base form) would be worse at it, but the exact nature of it seems to be up to the DM.

I would rule as a house rule that creatures without arms would have a -5 to all ride checks, minimum, but I can't find any evidence of something like this being official.